# Inject anonymous value into closed directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i was curious if it's possible to inject an value into a directives' close scope. I could't find anything related in the angularjs documentation so I tried something. Does anybody know if there is an more elegant way to solve this?

My approach so far:

```
app.directive('injectIntoScopeDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'inject.tpl.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

      angular.forEach(attrs, function(val, attr){
        // variables which should be injected must be prefixed with the inject keyword
        var match = attr.match(/^inject(.*)/);

        if( match !== null && match.length > 1 ){
          scope['injected' + match[1].toLowerCase()] = val
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DYFkqzI0zPKvG0K6xQoB?p=preview)

---

A new approach using the bindToController property. Much cleaner.

```
app.directive('injectIntoScopeDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: function(){

    },
    bindToController: {
      inject: '=' // allows us to bind an object to the directive controller
    },
    controllerAs: 'injectCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'inject.tpl.html'
    // no linking function needed
  }
});
```

Updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/n07NZ0vZ0dyCbIDiLtJI?p=preview) using bindToController property

Comment: you can try to reach the $rootScope and play with $broadcast and $on.
the $rootScope is shared and reachable from any scope in your app.
you need to inject it though to your directive function

Comment: If you need to do this you should probably rethink your design. Use the scope (or better the bindToController) property to define clear interfaces!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, I think using the bindToController property on the directive is the cleanest solution if you need to inject anonymous variables into the directive.

```
app.directive('injectIntoScopeDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    controller: function(){

    },
    bindToController: {
      inject: '=' // allows us to bind an object to the directive controller
    },
    controllerAs: 'injectCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'inject.tpl.html'
    // no linking function needed
  }
});
```

Working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/n07NZ0vZ0dyCbIDiLtJI?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the isolated scope of the directive :

```
<inject-into-scope-directive inject-foo="'i am foo'" inject-bar="'hello from bar'" some-other-attribute="'hello there'"></inject-into-scope-directive>
```

With :

```
app.directive('injectIntoScopeDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      injectedfoo:'=injectFoo',
      injectedbar:'=injectBar'
    },
    templateUrl: 'inject.tpl.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    }
  }
});
```

Angular says :

> The purpose is to separate the scope inside a directive from the scope
>   outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's inner scope. We
>   can do this by creating what we call an isolate scope. To do this, we
>   can use a directive's scope option.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I'm using the directive in several projects and I don't want to have fixed scope variables since they alter from project to project. Thats why I'm asking for anonymous variables. @LionC wrote about the bindToController property which is a fine solution for this problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

use @attr  in scope declaration:

```
scope: {injectedfoo:'@', injectedbar:'@'},
```

it binds to directives html attributes.

[Isolating the Scope of a Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CYs9ig?p=preview)